# Share Extension ▸ Firebase getDocuments in application Share Extenstion

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ios-sharesheet

I have an application which supports **Share Extension for image sharing** to the Firebase/Firestore

I am trying to request to get relevant documents to set my database record once image being uploaded.

**1. With getDocuments**

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("groups").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        // Further code implementation
}
```

**2. With addSnapshotListener**

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("groups").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        // Further code implementation
}
```

In both of the above code callback not executing.

When I am able to perform Auth.auth() user login action. Any help will save my app life.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: did you get it to work?

Comment: @bobski  Yes, it's working now